# How to upload iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus screenshots using iTMSTransport?

Tags: app-store-connect, itmstransporter

I've tried many times to upload iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus screenshots without success.

I've managed to get it working and without errors. The Terminal logs even show that the screenshots were in fact uploaded, but I couldn't see them for the languages I updated it.

Anyone having the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

Right now you cannot unfortunately. I've contacted apple support, so keep fingers crossed that they'll update the tool soon.

Comment: It is more like a comment rather than answer